# How to select the right iPhoneSimulator device from Visual Studio? (iPhoneSimulator always starts 3.5-inch device)

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to debug an Xamarin.iOS app on an iPhoneSimulator 4-inch device from Visual Studio but the iPhoneSimulator always starts with a 3.5-inch device. I can't find any option to select the right device.

Below you find a screenshot of the selections I can choose from in Visual Studio:

[image: Selection devices iPhoneSimulator]

However, in Xamarin Studio on my Mac everything works as expected. See below:

[image]

How can I select the right iPhoneSimulator device from Visual Studio?

*PS. Using: Windows 8, OSX Mavericks, VMWare Fusion 5, VS2012.4, Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio 1.8, Xamarin Studio 4.2.1, Xamarin.iOS 7.0.4, XCode 5.0.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio 1.8. With previous versions, you could switch the hardware in the simulator and it would remember that setting for the next deploy. This also had the side-effect that it didn't matter whether you selected Retina or not, you always ended up with the last simulator setting. While the Retina option works now, it is not possible to debug a on the iPhone 5 simulator from Visual Studio any more. You can, however, run it without the debugger by first deploying and then selecting `Hardware -> Device -> iPhone Retina (4-inch)` from the simulator menu.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it works indeed. But this way it is very though to debug anything... Do you know if this is going to be resolved soon?

Comment: ive come across this problem... seems like it's still not resolved